# How to map <leader><leader>f to a comma key in Vim?

Tags: vim

I found I've been using easy motion a lot recently, I want to map 
`<leader><leader>`<kbd>f</kbd> to a key, say <kbd>;</kbd>

so I add the following line to `vimrc` file

```
imap ; <leader><leader>f
```

but it doesn't work,

any idea?

Comment: You forgot to include the line.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, maybe that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: I'm still confused. Is `<Leader><Leader>` your easymotion trigger? What you do want to achieve with the mapping? Bypass easymotion? Define an alias?

Comment: Have you read `:help easymotion-custom-mappings`, and why doesn't that suit your needs?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat Yes I want to make a alias, so only one key input instead of 3

Comment: I tried your setting in my vimrc, and it works well. You can type "map ;" at the command line, and see what does ";" maps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `:imap` covers *insert mode* and would prevent you from inserting a `;` character into the text. The easymotion plugin is triggered from *normal mode*; therefore, you have to use `:nmap`:

```
nmap ; <leader><leader>f
```

Though the usual recommendation is to [use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) (it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion), here, because you're mapping to (the plugin's) mapping, you need to use `:nmap`.